# How to set "0" opacity to dwm and st?

Tags: c, linux, unix, archlinux, x-dwm

I installed the "alpha" patch to **dwm** and **st**.
and I changed the values to 0.

**dwm**:

```
static unsigned int baralpha        = 0x00;
static unsigned int borderalpha     = OPAQUE;
```

**st**:

```
float alpha = 0;
```

But still can't get it completely transparent.